# Can netty establish a connect connection with an https link?

Tags: sockets, https, proxy, netty

I want to complete a function with netty

http send data to netty -> netty proxy data to target https

I start a client to connet target link.

I tried proxy to http ,it's ok

But when i use https link , future.isSuccess() return false

```
 public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        if (msg instanceof FullHttpRequest) {
            FullHttpRequest request = (FullHttpRequest) msg;
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(ctx.channel().eventLoop())
                    .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
                    .handler(new HttpProxyInitializer(ctx.channel()));
            ChannelFuture f = b.connect("https://xxxx",443);
            outboundChannel = f.channel();
            f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                    if (future.isSuccess()) {
                        future.channel().writeAndFlush(msg);
                    } else {
                        ctx.channel().close();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

So is netty connet https not feasible?

Answer (score 0):

How you connect does not look correct.

You would use:

```
b.connect("hostname", 443)
```

Ensure your `HttpProxyInitializer` also add the `SslHandler` to the `ChannelPipeline`.

Also if things not work you should inspect the `future.cause()` as it will contain a `Throwable` which will provide details about why the operation failed.